# Ruby on rails getting data from hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, view

i just don't get it, where did i do wrong.
please highlight them for me.
Im testing a graph using gruff.

in ReportController

```
def mygruff
    @gr = Hash.new
    @gr["jan"] = 3
    @gr["feb"] = 6

    logger.info({#@gr.keys})
end
```

in my log, i did get 'janfeb'

in mygruff view

```
<%if @gr.blank?%>
   <%=No gruff%>
<%else%>
   <%=@gr.keys%>
<%end%>
```

I will get No gruff on mygruff page.
But i get it in my log.

Ive tried

```
object.empty? 
true

object.blank?
true

object.nil?
false
```

how to get the hash in my view?
please show me the way.thank you.

---

```
    def stat2
      @cus_t = Hash.new

      a = Gruff::Bar.new('500x350')
      a.theme = {
        :colors => ['#138F6A','#330000','#0aaafd','#FF0000','#00CD00','#ff6602', '#3bb003', '#1e90af', '#efba30', '#0aaaac'],
        :marker_color => '#aaa',
        :background_colors => ['#eaeaea', '#fff']
      }
      a.hide_title = true


      @customer = Customer.find(:all)
      @customer.each do |custs|
      @g_cus = Casedf.count(:all, :conditions=> "customer_id=" + custs.id.to_s)    
      a.data(custs.companyname, @g_cus)
     #@cus_t[custs.companyname] = @g_cus
      @cus_t.store(custs.companyname,@g_cus)

      end

      a.write("#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/images/customer.png") 
      $logger.info("hash keys #{@cus_t.keys}")


  end # end def
```

Here is what I did on my view:

```
<table>
<% if @cus_t.nil?%>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="6">No cus added so far<%=@cus_t.keys%>l</td>
    </tr>
<%else%>
<tr>
<td><%=@cus_t.keys%></td>
</tr>

<%end%>

</table>
```

So when I browse to stat2's page, I get nothing, but in my logs, the keys are printed out. I'm stumped, please help.

Comment: Why are you creating the hash that way? That would return nil on 1.8.7 and syntax error on 1.9.2

`@gr = {"jan" => 3, "feb" => 6}`  It's going to return false for nil because you've at least created a hash but haven't populated it. Try it out in irb. You're going to need `@gr.store("arg","arg")` to get it working.

Comment: yep im using 1.8.7. i just follow [link](http://ruby.about.com/od/rubyfeatures/a/hashes.htm).its actually '=' not '=>'.

Comment: caley, i did wht u told. but still i get nothing in mygruff page.urghhh...what did i do wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Hi Do you have in your action

```
def mygruff
  @gr = Hash.new
  @gr["jan"] = 3
  @gr["feb"] = 6

  logger.info({#@gr.keys})
end
```

it was not clear for me from comment

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby, hashes don't have a `blank?` method.  That method is added by Rails and there may be a bug with it.  Please try this in your view:

```
<% if @gr.empty? %>
  No gruff
<% end %>
<%= @gr.inspect %>  <!-- print regardless to see if there is data there -->
```

Comment: thanks david. i did wht u suggested. and i get this output: No cus added so farl
{}  ....i guess its empty. but in the controller, i print out @gr, i get the values. why it did not parse to its view?